# Упаковка/распаковка массива чисел в одно поле

Tags: java, числа

Есть некая лотерея в которой генерируется 5 чисел от 1 до 20-ти. Например: 3, 10, 2, 14, 9.

Вопрос на выбор:

- Как упаковать 5 выбранных чисел в одно поле INT32 чтобы компактно хранить его в БД и после при необходимости распаковать обратно в массив чисел для использования?
- Или подскажите по какой формуле это можно сделать?
- Или где почитать про алгоритмы решения подобных задач (на русском)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5

b = (((a1 * 32 + a2) * 32 + a3) * 32 + a4) * 32 + a5



a5 = b % 32
b = b / 32
a4 = b % 32
...
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я даже не представлял что так просто. Только вы допустили ошибку. Вместо `b = b - a1...5` нужно использовать `b = b / 32`. Пример [здесь](https://onlinegdb.com/By64_Eb0I).

Comment: @Rootware Да, пардон.